# How do i select text from a text field using 'CTRL A ' using selenium webdriver?

Tags: ruby, automation, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium webdriver with ruby.

```
clc = WAIT.until { driver.find_element(:id, 'embed-showembedcode') }
    driver.action.key_down(:control).click(clc).send_keys("a").key_up(:control).perform
```

This what i am using but i get a error..

```
{"testcase":"load: should check embed code","message":"erro
r - Cannot perform native interaction: Could not load native events component. \
n [\"[remote server] file:///C:/Users/nachiket/AppData/Local/Temp/webdriver-prof
ile20130705-5880-g873k8/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_com
ponent.js:8738:in `generateErrorForNativeEvents'\", \"[remote server] file:///C:
/Users/nachiket/AppData/Local/Temp/webdriver-profile20130705-5880-g873k8/extensi
ons/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:8771:in `FirefoxDrive
```

Comment: Do you want to get that text out from the desired element ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Humm.. Look [`Selenium::WebDriver::Element#text`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Element.html#text-instance_method)

So use :

```
elem = wait.until {
element = driver.find_element(:id, 'embed-showembedcode')
element if element.displayed?
}
puts elem.text # => target text will be printed here
```

Now to fix the error,I would suggest you always do some machine representation test as below. It is not needed that [`Selenium::WebDriver::Keys`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Keys.html) mentioned mapping will be good to work in your machine:

```
require "selenium-webdriver"

puts Selenium::WebDriver::Keys::KEYS
# => {:null=>"\uE000", :cancel=>"\uE001", :help=>"\uE002", :backspace=>"\uE003", :tab=>"\uE004", 
# :clear=>"\uE005", :return=>"\uE006",:enter=>"\uE007", :shift=>"\uE008",
# :left_shift=>"\uE008", :control=>"\uE009",.. }

elem = wait.until {
element = driver.find_element(:id, 'embed-showembedcode')
element if element.displayed?
}
driver.action.key_down("\uE009").click(elem).send_keys("a").key_up("\uE009").perform
```

Comment: @user1177636 Hum.. you are right. Both way I have provided my suggestion to OP. :)

Comment: @user1177636 God bless you.. :D probably I caught the pain of OP,although he couldn't express.. on the first place.. :))